# Swift tableview cell doesn't save the state with different identifier

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am very confused on the reuse of the cells.

I have a table, each cell is a cell with a switch on it. If I toggle a switch I set the background color of that cell to a different color. However every time I scroll these changes don't persist.

I am subclassing UITalbeViewCell to create my own custom cell. Each cell has a different identifier. However when I scroll through the table, whatever changes I made to the cell still doesn't save. I've read similar questions but none of them worked.. Some suggested subclass which I did, some suggested use different identifier which I also did...

Here is the code of my tableview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let key = Array(dataSource[indexPath.section].keys)[indexPath.row]

    let cell = CellWithSwitch.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: key)
    cell.awakeFromNib()

    let val = Array(dataSource[indexPath.section].values)[indexPath.row]
    cell.switchView?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    if let index = key.firstIndex(of: "."){
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(key.suffix(from: key.index(index, offsetBy: 1)))
    }else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = key;
    }
    cell.switchView?.setOn(val, animated: true)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a subclass 2) Reuse the cell 3) Never call `awakeFromNib` yourself. 4) You have to save the state of the switch in the `dataSource` 5) Use a callback closure rather than target/action.

Comment: @vadian subclass of tableviewCell? I am already subclassing it... what is the reuse identifier for if it's still reusing it even with different identifiers?

Comment: What is the purpose of different identifiers for the same kind of cell?

Comment: @vadian oh so it's actually for each kind..I thought it meant for each instance.

Comment: No, it's for each kind. Design the cell in Interface Builder, assign the identifier and use `dequeueReusableCell`. But the actual issue is that you don't save the state of the switch in the data source and update it in `cellForRow`.

Comment: @vadian Another question, I am adding the switch in awakeFromNib function, if I don't call it myself then how should I even initialize the switch?

Comment: Again, design everything in Interface Builder (use a **custom** cell). That's much more efficient.

Comment: You should be calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. If you don't know what that is, Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change array value in `switchChange` action

lets i take array for switch as below:

```
var arrSwitch = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
```

Below is my `cellForRowAt` Method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! customCell
        cell. switchView.setOn(self.arrSwitch[indexPath.row], animated: false)
        cell. switchView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell. switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onSwitchTap(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return cell
    }
```

Here is my `onSwitchTap` Action

```
@IBAction func onSwitchTap(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        self.arrSwitch[sender.tag] = !self.arrSwitch[sender.tag]
    }
```

Now on scroll it will persist last changes you have done.